# Flutter select multiple images from gallery

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to upload images to firebase. But "image_picker" plugin only allows selecting a single image at a time. Is there any way I can make that select multiple images at a time?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to write your own plugin or contribute to the existing *image_picker* flutter plugin.

There's been already couple of requests ([#1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16054), [#2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17591)) in the [Flutter GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter) repo for this feature. If you don't want to write native code, then I guess hang tight?

Comment: I guess I would wait till I complete implementing other features in my app.

Comment: Are you still waiting for this? Have you found any other solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

See the link:
To select multiple images from gallery:

The flutter_multiple_image_picker plugin allows an user to select multiple images from gallery . The method initMultiPickUp() in main.dart is called to select the images. where we define the number of images to be selected by calling FlutterMultiImagePicker class within it –

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjPnPmEjsbcAhXCp48KHZ2BDtwQFjAQegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpub.dartlang.org%2Fpackages%2Fflutter_multiple_image_picker&usg=AOvVaw0qHzgl7_8HmahBEXZHmv3l

Comment: please add some clarification instead of just pasting a link

Comment: The flutter_multiple_image_picker plugin allows an user to select multiple images from gallery  . The method initMultiPickUp() in main.dart is called to select the images.  where we define the number of images to be selected by calling FlutterMultiImagePicker class within it